# Google Analytics SDK for Android v2 (Beta) Manual Dispatch

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am new to using Google Analytics and I am trying to integrate it with my Android application. Going though the official documentation for Dispatch below is an excerpt pulled directly from there:

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/dispatch
>
> > Apart from relying on periodic dispatch, there may be times when you want to manually dispatch your hits. For example, you could bundle your dispatches with other HTTP requests made by your application 
> >     to reduce overhead.

My question is, how do I bundle the dispatch with my other HTTP connections within the app. I am using DefaulHttpClient for my app to make HTTP calls. I have searched for quite some time and I have not found any samples or any suggestions that could make this work.

It would be really helpful if someone can point me in the right direction to have this implemented.

P.S I cannot post any code samples due to the restrictions of my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using EasyTracker, just call [EasyTracker.getInstance(context).dispatch()](http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadocs/com/google/android/apps/analytics/easytracking/EasyTracker.html#dispatch%28%29) whenever you are making the HTTP request. Unless it is currently doing automatic dispatching, it will send up to 30 queued hits.

Comment: Ok so if I got you right , before I make a call to httpclient.execute() I should call EasyTracker.getInstance(context).dispatch() ?

Comment: An additional question to the above, lets assume I am tracking multiple activities and there are 30 queued hits which belong to different activities. When I call the dispatch manually, irrespective of the context I am passing, would the EasyTracker dispatch all the hits?

Comment: Call dispatch() either immediately before or after the other HTTP request. The overhead that you are trying to reduce is the one associated with establishing an active mobile connection - the radio switches from active to passive connection depending on the amount of stuff it needs to send and receive, and that switch is pretty costly regarding battery life. That's why it's better to try to send/receive big chunks of data at the same time, risking some data transfer overhead, than to establish frequent short-lived connections that drain the user's battery.

Comment: About your second question: yes, I believe that the hits get dispatched regardless of which activity you are in. The tracker instance is per application, not per activity.

Comment: Perfect!! thank you very much for your help, that was fast. I am very new to stackoverflow so I am not sure how to vote and mark this as answered but I am gonna figure it out and will do it in a while.

Comment: Ok, so I dont have a reputation of 15 or above and I am not allowed to vote up. However, I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: No problem, I recently had a similar issue. Please try to give something back to the community when you know the answer to somebody's question :)

Comment: Sure.. I will start doing that :)